# c++ shared_ptr with std::function or double (*SOME_NAME)(double);

Tags: c++, function, shared-ptr

Q1) Given that we have

`typedef double (*function_t)(double);`

or

`typedef std::function<double(double)> function_t;`

how do we define

`std::shared_ptr<function_t> ptr_func = ???`

for some function.

Let's say we want a `shared_ptr` to an object already defined (forgetting for now that it defeats the purpose - but I'm needing this). As an example consider the following for an object of type `double`.

```
struct null_deleter
{
    void operator() (void const *) const {};
};

int main()
{
    // define object
    double b=0;

    // define shared pointer
    std::shared_ptr<double> ptr_store;
    ptr_store.reset(&b,null_deleter()); // this works and behaves how you would expect
}
```

Although if we do the same for a `shared_ptr` of type `function_t`, i.e.

```
double f (double x)
{
    // some_function + return
}

int main()
{

    // define shared pointer
    std::shared_ptr<function_t> ptr_store;
    ptr_store.reset(&f,null_deleter()); // ERROR: does not work
}
```

The error returned is something like the following:

```
error: cannot convert 'double (*)(double)' to 'double (**)(double)' in initialization
```

or in the case of `std::function`

```
error: cannot convert 'double (*)(double)' to 'std::function<double(double)>*' in initialization
```

It's clear not the correct type is passed, and probably we are not allowed to do this (?)

Note: compiled with `g++4-7-2` version with `-std=c++11 -O3` on windows MinGW

**The few answers work well, I'll reply back to you all sometime today. it's 6.30 in the morning here and i've not gone to sleep yet. My whole design pattern for what I'm implementing is probably wrong, Hopefully I can explain a bit later :|**

Comment: One way that'll probably work is std::bind(&f).

Comment: @Guy That doesn't work either I get an error `mismathed types '_Tp1*' and 'std::_Bind (double (*())(double))`. But I'll see what I can do with `std::bind`, not used it before.

Comment: I cooked some example for you.  Not sure if that's exactly what you want (or why you want it) but it shows you how these classes can play together.

Comment: the functor should be a replacement to your traditional function pointer so I don't understand why you want the shared pointer (though you can certainly do that)...  Also shared pointer isn't for pointing at static objects (you kind of said that, defeating the purpose) though you can force it in my answer below...

Comment: You realize `shared_ptr<function_t>` is a smart pointer to pointer to function, not a smart pointer to function....

Answer (score 0):

This is contrived but is the best I could come up with without understanding what you're actually trying to do exactly:

```
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function<double(double)> function_t;

double f(double t)
{
    return t*5;
}

int main(int argc, char*argv[])
{
    // You usually want to attach the shared pointer to a dynamically allocated object
    std::shared_ptr<function_t> ptr;
    ptr.reset(new function_t(std::bind(&f, std::placeholders::_1)));
    std::cout << (*ptr)(5.0);

    // But we can attach the smart pointer to a local function object on the stack (BAD IDEA)
    function_t fff = std::bind(&f, std::placeholders::_1);
    ptr.reset(&fff);
    std::cout << (*ptr)(5.0);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I try to stay clear of raw function pointers, and prefer to wrap them up in a function object.  Following that approach, the code below works.  The `shared_ptr` wants to contain a pointer to an object of the type given as its first template parameter, so if you use

```
std::shared_ptr<function_t>
```

then it has to contain a

```
function_t*
```

You had that part right.

Normally, one would pass in a pointer to a dynamically-allocated object, as in

```
std::shared_ptr<function_t> ptr_store( new function_t( f ) );
```

but in your case you want to pass the address of an object that's already on the stack.

So I created a local `function_t` object named `foo`, and then passed its address - along with the `null_deleter` - to the shared_ptr, and everything worked.

I hope this helps!

P.S. I used Microsoft Visual Studio 2010

```
#include <functional>
#include <memory>
#include <iostream>

typedef std::function<double(double)> function_t;

struct null_deleter
{
  void operator() (void const *) const {};
};

double f (double x)
{
  return 2.0 * x;
}

int main( int argc, char* argv[] )
{
  // A function object on the stack
  function_t foo( f );

  // Putting this in a local scope to verify that when the shared_ptr goes
  // out of scope, nothing bad happens.
  double result1;
  {
  std::shared_ptr<function_t> ptr_store;
  ptr_store.reset( &foo, null_deleter() );

  result1 = (*ptr_store)( 10.0 );
  std::cout << result1 << std::endl;
  }
  // ptr_store has now been destroyed

  // Calling the foo function object again just to be sure it's still OK
  double result2 = foo( 5.0 );
  std::cout << result2 << std::endl;
}
```